# Flask error out with dill.dill message when loading saved file

Tags: python, machine-learning, amazon-s3, pickle, dill

I saved two files(model, vectorizer) in s3 and trying to download from s3 and run it with my flask app file.  But, this currently returns dill.dill (no module named error). Funny thing is that I don't import "dill" anywhere but it looks like it's importing in internally and complains.

```
    import flask
    from flask import Flask, request, render_template, jsonify
    from sklearn.externals import joblib
    import numpy as np
    from scipy import misc
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
    import boto3
    import pickle 

    BUCKET_NAME = 'xxxx'
    MODEL_FILE_NAME = 'text-classification-model-v1.pk' 
    VECTORIZER_FILE_NAME = 'word_vectorizer.pk'
    ACCESS_KEY="QQQQ"
    SECRET_KEY="ZZZZZ"
    S3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY, region_name='us-west-2')
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
    def index():
        payload = [request.args.get('description')]     
        prediction = predict_(payload)
        return parse_data()

    def predict_(payload):
        transformed_text_features = load_vectorizer(payload)
        return load_model(MODEL_FILE_NAME).predict(transformed_text_features) 

    def parse_data():
        return 'xxx'

    def load_vectorizer(payload):
        with open("downloaded_vectorizer.pk", 'wb') as data:
            S3.download_fileobj(BUCKET_NAME, VECTORIZER_FILE_NAME, data)
        infile = open("downloaded_vectorizer.pk","rb")
        loaded_vectorizer = joblib.load(infile)  
        infile.close()
        transformed_text_features = loaded_vectorizer.transform(payload)  
        return transformed_text_features

    def load_model(model):
        with open("downloaded_model_textclassification.pkl", 'wb') as data:  
            S3.download_fileobj(BUCKET_NAME, MODEL_FILE_NAME, data)
        infile = open("downloaded_model_textclassification.pkl","rb")    
        model = pickle.load(infile) 
        infile.close()
        return model 

    ==========
    error message
    ==========
      File "\flask\predict_commodity.py", line 32, in index
        prediction = predict_(payload)
      File "\flask\predict_commodity.py", line 38, in predict_
        transformed_text_features = load_vectorizer(payload)
      File "\flask\predict_commodity.py", line 60, in load_vectorize
        loaded_vectorizer = joblib.load(infile)
      File " \lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 568, in load
        obj = _unpickle(fobj)
      File " \lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 508, in _unpickle
        obj = unpickler.load()
      File " \anaconda3\Lib\pickle.py", line 1050, in load
        dispatch[key[0]](self)
      File "\Lib\pickle.py", line 1338, in load_global
        klass = self.find_class(module, name)
      File "\Lib\pickle.py", line 1388, in find_class
        __import__(module, level=0)
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dill.dill'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the your code you're using `pickle` and `sklearn.externals.joblib`. That can be a problem.

Also, you can try to update the package: `pip install dill --upgrade`. That helped me with the same problem.